# Qual è il significato di "sollevato ad onda" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia della bambina perduta*, di Elena Ferrante, ho letto:

> Era un insieme di chissà quanti quaderni di scuola simili ai due che avevo sotto gli occhi: banalissimi quaderni luridi con il bordo destro, in basso, **sollevato a onda**.

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "sollevato a onda" nella frase precedente. Significa "incurvato in modo ondulato"? Ho cercato la voce "onda" in alcuni dizionari, ma questo non ha chiarito il mio dubbio.

Comment: Sì, secondo me significa proprio che l'angolo del quaderno si era deformato nel tempo.
Mi vengono in mente nelle cose del genere:
http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/images/m/mSB8XnRoq9Ixgf5e7gHiEMw/s-l225.jpg
http://www.elledecor.it/var/elleit/storage/images/media/images/05-4-libri-da-leggere-consigliati-designer-libro-luca-nichetto/15894557-1-ita-IT/05-4-libri-da-leggere-consigliati-designer-libro-luca-nichetto_reference.jpg

Comment: Non credo di aver sentito questa espressione, ma anche a me dà un'impressione simile a quella di Charo e Riccardo (e più specificamente mi fa pensare a un quaderno un po' rovinato dall'umidità, ma probabilmente ci leggo troppo).

Comment: umidità, oppure schiacciato in modo non uniforme...

Comment: @Charo, mi suona di metafora. Dove hai controllato di preciso? Qui, anche se in plurale ma capirai a cosa alludo, http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/onda_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/ per "a onda" si legge  **Locuz. prep.: a onde 1. [che ha la superficie o il profilo simile a quello della superficie del mare quando è mosso dalle onde]**, avevi giá letto quel link? Se si allora il senso fig ti deve essere chiaro chiarissimo, o hai dubbi a capire "sollevato"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Più che alle orecchie penso che l'autrice si riferisca a quella deformazione che assumono i quaderni quando, a forza di usarli, il calore e il sudore della mano fanno "arricciare" i bordi esterni delle pagine (quelli a destra quando il quaderno è chiuso). Una cosa così, più o meno: http://www.domandeimpossibili.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/carta-758x398.jpg

Le orecchie a volte si formano perché si butta il quaderno nello zaino o nella cartella senza alcuna cura. Il quaderno finisce sotto a qualcos'altro, si piega, si stropiccia, si sgualcisce. Ma penso che l'autrice intenda *connotare* che la deformazione del quaderno è dovuta alle molte ore di impegno e di sudore (fisico e metaforico) passate sul quaderno.

Answer (score -2):

Penso voglia dire che nel quaderno via sia un'"orecchia" ovvero una piega a forma di onda verso l'alto.

Comment: È un modo colloquiale per indicare le pieghe nei bordi del quaderno/libro: https://www.google.it/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.torricellapeligna.com%2Fphotogallery%2FMem12-Fig28.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.torricellapeligna.com%2FMemories12.htm&docid=VHTZ_jSP4jxaOM&tbnid=GI4qLyJkz_zeOM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwihmPrkheHTAhWLC8AKHTVrCXEQMwgyKAAwAA..i&w=371&h=234&bih=615&biw=360&q=quaderno%20con%20orecchie&ved=0ahUKEwihmPrkheHTAhWLC8AKHTVrCXEQMwgyKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: Ti è sfuggito quello che intendevo, fa niente. Tuttavia per "orecchia" intendi come da qui: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/orecchia/ **a. Piegatura che si fa volontariamente nell’angolo superiore della pagina di un libro, di un quaderno, di un foglio, per segnalare e poter ritrovare un passo particolare, oppure, involontariamente, per negligenza, disordine, incuria.**?

Comment: @mle: Vorresti fare l'edit un'altra volta?

Comment: Si esattamente quel significato

Comment: @mle: L'hai fatto allo stesso momento di me, quindi adesso il sistema non mi lascia accettarlo.

Comment: @user154508, nella citazione di Charo si legge "con il bordo destro" e non "angolo superiore".. mi sfugge qualcosa?

Comment: @mle: Ma penso che la tua modifica al post sia meglio di quello che ho fatto io.

Comment: Le orecchie che si formano per disordine possono trovarsi anche nel bordo destro in basso.

Comment: non riesco a seguirti piú, dove si trovano ste orecchie? Giú? Se si, oltre a leggere il libro o altro al contrario (doverosa battuta, concedimela), allora il senso non é quello della treccani, o *fai le orecchie* a tutto il bordo destro basso della pagina (o.O) ?! Secondo Treccani un´orecchia è come questa http://bit.ly/2qTOclJ .. Puoi provare a fare un´orecchia ad un libro/foglio/quaderno e mandarci la foto?!

Comment: https://www.google.it/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.torricellapeligna.com%2Fphotogallery%2FMem12-Fig28.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.torricellapeligna.com%2FMemories12.htm&docid=VHTZ_jSP4jxaOM&tbnid=GI4qLyJkz_zeOM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwihmPrkheHTAhWLC8AKHTVrCXEQMwgyKAAwAA..i&w=371&h=234&bih=615&biw=360&q=quaderno%20con%20orecchie&ved=0ahUKEwihmPrkheHTAhWLC8AKHTVrCXEQMwgyKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: Si possono anche fare delle orecchie volutamente, nella parte superiore della pagina a destra per tenere il segno.